# How to declare a module which has a dot in a file name?

Tags: rust

I would like to add suffixes to the name of file modules

```
module1/
- mod.rs
- module.suffix1.rs
- module.suffix2.rs
- module.suffix3.rs
main.rs
```

```
// module1/mod.rs

pub use module.seuffix1;
              ^ Error

pub use module.suffix2;
              ^ Error

pub use module.suffix3;
              ^ Error
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S. I'm not sure if this convention is "okay" in rust, but `module_suffix2.rs` looks messy when a file name consists of two words - `my_modyle_suffix.rs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include dots in names. You can create a module `module` and have `suffix`, `suffix2` and `suffix3` as submodules, accessing them with `module::suffix`. If you prefer to keep the directory structure flat, you can use [the `#[path]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute).